# Rails, polymorphic association. Destroy with "touch: true", useless steps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I'm on **Rails 5**.

I have a polymorphic association like this:

*models/enjoy_level.rb*:

```
class EnjoyLevel < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :enjoyable, polymorphic: true, touch: true, optional: true
end
```

*models/mother.rb*:

```
class Mother < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :enjoy_level, as: :enjoyable, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :enjoy_level
end
```

If I destroy one `mother` (which have `touch: true` option) it still:

- destroy the `enjoy_level` one before;
- set `Mother` `update_at` to now();
- and finally destroy this `Mother` record one.

**The first and second steps are useless**, right?

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable touching at the ActiveRecord level when you destroy the parent object:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.no_touching do
  mother.destroy
end
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

> :touch - If true, the associated object will be touched (the
>   updated_at/on attributes set to now) when this record is either saved
>   or destroyed. If you specify a symbol, that attribute will be updated
>   with the current time in addition to the updated_at/on an attribute.

So when you are destroying `mother`, you are calling the `dependent: destroy` dependencies at first, that are your `enjoy_level` objects and because they have `touch: true` you are touching the `mother` object back (because it also updates it on destroy). 
So maybe 2nd query is useless in the current scenario, but they work as planned.

Comment: So are you saying my flow is correct? Is this the way Rails go? Am I wrong?

Comment: @JohnSam the Rails is going this way because you've programmed it this way. You can remove `touch: true` and you will not have second query and it will make more sense.

Comment: But I need it because I need to update the updated_at column when I edit enjoyable... How to do?

Comment: @JohnSam well, in this case if you don't want additional update queries on destroy it will be easier to remove `touch: true` option and make a callback :before_update